# React-Native Invalid hook call for Flat List Render Item

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

So i have a react-native flat list where i use hooks in each `FlatList` `renderItem`, something like this,

```
export const RenderEntityList = (props) => {
    const { entityList } = props;
    const getEntityName = useCallBack((entity) => {
        //...get Entity name from list
    }, [entityList]);
    return <FlatList
              data={entityList}
              renderItem={RenderEntity({ getEntityName })}
           />
};


const RenderEntity = (props) => {
    const { getEntityName } = props;
    return (props) => {
        const { item: entity } = props;
        // This is where i get the error Invalid hook call;
        const [entityName, setEntityName] = useState('');
        useEffect(() => {
            setEntityName(getEntityName(entity))
        }, [entity])
        return <ListItem
                  title={entityName}
               />
};
```

I am not sure what exactly i am doing wrong.
Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks Regards. 
Amol

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are using `RenderEntity` as `function` instead of a `functional component` :

Change this

```
renderItem={RenderEntity({ getEntityName })}
```

With :

```
renderItem={({item, index, separators}) => <RenderEntity item={item} getEntityName={getEntityName}/> }
```

Comment: Hmmm, I will give it a try. Just out of curiosity, can we use currying as I mentioned in the question?

Comment: first check if `getEntityName` is returning anything or not, if its returning then you can use it

Comment: So get entityname returns a string, can I use React.createElement ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9

Comment: This answer show a great understanding of arrow function vs functional components. Thanks for sharing!